# SMTP Relay available in Pro Account?

Tags: trigger, marketing-cloud

I am trying to verify that [SMTP Relay](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/triggered_emails/sending_exacttarget_emails_via_smtp_relay/) is available in the PRO account for Marketing Cloud. Based on my research this may not be a function available. Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

That feature was made available through the Early Adopter Program which is not currently accepting additional participants.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's available.

Comment: https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/triggered_emails/sending_exacttarget_emails_via_smtp_relay/