# Marketing Cloud to send emails through Amazon SES

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

We would like our SFMC instance to send emails through Amazon Simple Email Service (SES) which is a standard in our organization.

Is it possible to create an SMTP Relay to route the email sends to the Amazon SES?

I know that some time ago this functionality was offered in the 'Early Adopters' program. Is it publically available right now?

Comment: I would refer to this question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137018/smtp-relay-available-in-pro-account

Comment: Thanks a lot. I saw this one but as it's from 2016, I thought that maybe something has changed since then.